# Trouble finding out why string is being copied twice

Tags: c

I'm copying a string but for some reason the string is being copied twice.

```
bool check(const char* word) {
    // copy the word
    char *copy = malloc(sizeof(word));
    strcpy(copy, word);

    printf("word %s\n", word);
    printf("copy %s\n", copy);

    return false;
}
```

The output of this function is

```
word myWord
copy myWord
myWord
```

If i remove the '\n' character in the printf for copy, the output changes to

```
word myWord
copy myWordmyWord
```

I've tried walking through this code with a debugger but the debugger is showing the value of copy to be "myWord"

Does anyone have an idea what may be happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to allocate `strlen(word) + 1` bytes.  `sizeof(word)` returns the number of bytes for storing a pointer.

Comment: That did it! I understand there wasn't enough memory for the null character, but how does the word get printed twice? According to the debugger, word and copy are not adjacent in memory.

Comment: if your debugger has a memory window, use it to view the bytes at the allocated address.  step thru your code to see how this changes.